# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: is invalid for option "hostname"

Tags: node.js, http, dns

I am getting this error:

```
unhandledRejection: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "blue-test.cle1x.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" is invalid for option "hostname"
    at Object.lookupService (dns.js:173:11)
    at /app/main.js:32:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at getDNSInfo (/app/main.js:31:36)
    at /app/main.js:113:12
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:112:68)
    at Server.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:709:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:17)
```

I used this call:

```
  const dns = require('dns');
  dns.lookupService(host, port, (err, hostname, service) => {
    console.log('dns resolved:', {hostname, service, err});
    resolve({err, hostname, service});
  });
```

and hostname is passed as host, so anyone know what's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `dns.lookupService()` is `address`, not `host`. According to Node.js [document](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookupservice_address_port_callback):

> **dns.lookupService(address, port, callback)**
>
> Resolves the given address and port into a hostname and service using the operating system's underlying getnameinfo implementation.

If you want to resolve `blue-test.cle1x.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com` to its IP address, `dns.lookup()` is the right choice.